# returning random int from method to array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, return

In my code i have static int method that should return an array of random integers. The problem is when i print an array, only the last number is random int, and other ints are all zeros.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] array = mtd(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
    }
}
public static int[] mtd(int b)
{
    int[] arr = new int[b];
    Array.Resize<int>(ref arr, b);
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr.SetValue(rand.Next(1, 5), arr.Length - 1);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Did you set breakpoints, step through the code, inspect your variables and look at the documentation for `Array.SetValue()`  so you can confirm that this code does what you expect it to? Hint: you're not using `i`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `for` loop in your method `mtd` you are always setting the last value of your array `arr` by using `arr.Length - 1`. Use `i` instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = rand.Next(1, 5);
}
```

Or with `arr.SetValue`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr.SetValue(rand.Next(1, 5), i);
}
```

Comment: okay, i get it now, so the problem was my array.resize line. I was trying to use "i" but it could not work back then.

Comment: You didn't need to use `Array.Resize` because you were setting the size of the array before when using `new int[b]`.

Answer (score 0):

Working one :

```
public static int[] mtd(int b)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[b];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr.SetValue(rand.Next(1, 5), i);
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

EDIT : Btw the Array.resize is useless here, you already define the length of your array.  ( `new int[b]` set the length of the array to b )

Your problem was that you never used `i`, so you just set the value of the last value of your array.

Answer (score 0):

I modified and simplified your code:

```
    public static int[] mtd(int b)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[b];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = rand.Next(1, 5);
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: arr[i] = rand.Next(1, 5) does look much better.

Comment: Thank you. @Adi543.